# Execute @Sql after @BeforeEach in Integration Test

Tags: spring, spring-boot, integration-testing

currently I'm working on integration test, and this one controller cover many tables, so instead insert transactional data using **@BeforeEach**, I want use sql script and I tried like this..

```
  @Sql(scripts = {"classpath:/business-test-data.sql"})
  public class IntegrationTest extend AbstractIT {

    @BeforeEach
    void init() {
      // method from AbstractIT
      // Clear DB, Redis, Kafka, etc
    }
   
    @Test
    void someTest(){}
```

.. and turn out Spring executed **business-test-data.sql** before clear DB.

so, how can I execute **business-test-data.sql** after clear db? any suggestion or other approach would be appreciated. Thank you.

**Notes :**

1. as for schema and master data, they already executed along with embedded postgres initialization, and I want to avoid insert transactional data using this script.
2. Clear DB is a method inherited from *AbstractIT* class, change how to clear table looks like would impacted other integration test as well, so I want to avoid it too.

Answer (score 1):

`@Sql` on a **class** level will be executed once before the test suite is run.

`@BeforeEach` will be executed before each **test method**.

So It looks like you need your `@Sql` to run before each method as well. you can either do it manually in the same method or annotate methods with `@Sql` instead (so not at class level but at method level)

See more here: [Quick Guide on Loading Initial Data with Spring Boot - @Sql](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-data-sql-and-schema-sql#sqlannotation)

Comment: I tried this, and no difference. After a bit research, @Sql has attribute _executionPhase_ , and by default set to _BEFORE_TEST_METHOD_, so looks like by default the script executed before every test case.